# react native: Displays a single table with the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In my code I expect to get only one table with the data but what happens is that I get a lot of tables with the same data and it is not clear to me why.
Lots of tables are accepted and I should get only one table.
I would be happy to help with this

```
export const ActionModal = (props: any) => {
    const { pointsData } = useGetPoints();
    const [tableHead] = useState(['אזור', 'אתר', 'נ`ק איסוף', 'מיקום']);
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

    const arrangeData = () => {
        let rows: any[] = [];
        pointsData.forEach(e => {
            let row = [e.area, e.site, e.gatheringPoint, e.location];
            rows.push(row);
        });
        setTableData(rows);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        arrangeData();
    }, []);

    const renderItem = ({ item }: any) => (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <View style={styles.tableView}>
                <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff' }}>
                    <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text} />
                    <Rows data={tableData} textStyle={styles.text} />
                </Table>
            </View>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{item.area}, {item.site}, {item.gatheringPoint}, {item.location}</Text>
        </View>
    )

    return (
        <Modal
            animationType={'slide'}
            transparent={false}
            visible={props.actionModalVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => {
                console.log('Modal has been closed.');
            }}>
            <View style={styles.modal}>

                {pointsData.length ?
                    <FlatList
                        data={pointsData}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.gatheringID}
                    /> :
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />}

            </View>
            <Button
                title="סגור"
                onPress={props.onClose}
            />
        </Modal>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Table are rendered inside a item of flatlist
the function renderItem will repeate like a number of row of you array , this why you get lot of table ..
to fix this you need to pull out of flatlist like this to rendering table once time  :

```
export const ActionModal = (props: any) => {
const { pointsData } = useGetPoints();
const [tableHead] = useState(['אזור', 'אתר', 'נ`ק איסוף', 'מיקום']);
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

const arrangeData = () => {
    let rows: any[] = [];
    pointsData.forEach(e => {
        let row = [e.area, e.site, e.gatheringPoint, e.location];
        rows.push(row);
    });
    setTableData(rows);
}

useEffect(() => {
    arrangeData();
}, []);

const renderItem = ({ item }: any) => (
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 18 }}>{item.area}, {item.site}, {item.gatheringPoint}, {item.location}</Text>
)

return (
    <Modal
        animationType={'slide'}
        transparent={false}
        visible={props.actionModalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
            console.log('Modal has been closed.');
        }}>
        <View style={styles.modal}>
            
            {pointsData.length ?
                <View style={styles.item}>
                <View style={styles.tableView}>
                    <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff' }}>
                        <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text} />
                        <Rows data={tableData} textStyle={styles.text} />
                    </Table>
                </View>
                    <FlatList
                        data={pointsData}
                        renderItem={renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.gatheringID}
                    /> 
                </View>:
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" />}

        </View>
        <Button
            title="סגור"
            onPress={props.onClose}
        />
    </Modal>
);
```

};